# What order does the if and else statment process?

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and I got this question wrong on my hw. I answered "Goodbye". The correct answer was "Welcome". I am confused why it skips over the else statement when else is not inside either of the if statements. I specifically thought that else means if the if statement is wrong do this instead. What is the correct way to think about this?

What will be displayed to the user?

```
var x = 1, y = 7;
var message = "Welcome";

if (x < 2) {
   if (y > 10) {
     message = "Hello";
   }
}
else {
   message = "Goodbye";
}
window.alert(message);
```

Comment: You have an extra paranthesis. at the end, just after the window.alert

Comment: Output should be `Welcome`

Comment: initial value of message of `Welcome`, now x is 1 so it is less than 2 so it enters the first if block, not it tests for the value of y, since y is 7 the condition is not satisfied and that block don't have a else block, so the value of message is not modified

Answer (score 3):

For explanation you can draw the program as a diagram so you can go only down and never up. Then it should be clear and visible why the answer is "Welcome".

```
                      x = 1
                      y = 7
                message = "Welcome"
                        |
                        |
                    ( x < 2 )
                     /     \
                    /       \
                 true      false
                  /           \
                 /             \
           ( y > 10 )    message = "Goodbye"
            /      \
           /        \
        true       false
         /            \
        /              \
message = "Hello"    (nothing)

------------------------v--------------------
                        |
                        |
                  alert(message)
```

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the editing. It seems like I'm a little bit tired

Answer (score 1):

Because `x` is less than two the `else` statement is ignored. As the check on the `y` variable is contained within the outer `if` block it has no effect on the outer `if`.

```
var x = 1, y = 7;
var message = "Welcome";

if (x < 2) {               /* True (x is less than 2) */
   if (y > 10) {
     message = "Hello";    /* False (y isn't greater than 10) */
   }
}
else {                     /* False (x isn't greater than or equal to 2) */
   message = "Goodbye";
}
```

It *would* enter the `else` block if the outer `if` combined both conditions, as this would evaluate to `false`:

```
if (x < 2 && y > 10)
```

Comment: So it skips over the else block because else is not inside the if statement?

Comment: @Jice it skips over the `else` block because the condition for it to hit the `else` isn't met. The `else` here will only fire if `x` is greater than or equal to 2. If the first `if` evaluates to `true`, its `else` condition will not be hit.

Comment: I was thinking the else would trigger because the second if statement was false, but know i realize it corresponds the the first one only.

Answer (score 0):

Your else statement will only be executed if your first if statement is false and will not be executed if you second if statement is false.

```
if (x < 2 && y > 10) {
   message = "Hello";
}
else {
   message = "Goodbye";
}
```

This will have the correct behavior.